# How to calculate this series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} (-1)^n\frac{n+1}{n!}$$

I've been working on it for one WHOLE day, still have no clue. I think it's time to seek for help....>< Any hint to compute this series?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** We have 
$$e^{-x}=1-x+\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^5}{5!}+\cdots.$$

Multiply both sides by $x$, and differentiate term by term.

**Another way:** Express $\dfrac{n+1}{n!}$ as $\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}+\dfrac{1}{n!}$, and use your knowledge about the series for $e^{-x}$.

Comment: OMG~ you are incredible!! took u less than one minute!! but I got one more question, after multiplying by x then differentiate it, the derivative of x*e^(-x) when plug in 1 is zero, so I guess that's the answer, right? (just a little surprise it ends up with 0....)

Comment: Ah~ I actually tried to separate the fraction like you said in the beginning, but i didn't relate it to Taylor series of exponential function....

Comment: Separating is actually easier, you get the series for $e^{-1}$ minus the series for $e^{-1}$. And you don't even need to know what they are the series for, you get term by term cancellation.  I gave the fancier way first because the trick of differentiating or integrating term by term can be a very useful one.

Comment: yes~~~~ I'm soooo happy now~ it haunted me for the whole day!! Thanks so much!!

Comment: You are welcome. A useful trick to remember, when you want $\sum \frac{n}{2^n}$ say. We have $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$. Differentiate, set $x=1/2$. That's almost our sum.

Answer (score 2):

Neatest way:
$$
(-1)^n \frac{n+1}{n!} = (-1)^n\left(\frac1{n!}+\frac1{(n-1)!}\right)
$$
So, reordering the sum (and explicitly including the $n=0$ case, where it's just $1$), you have
$$
1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} = 1 - \frac{(-1)^0}{0!} = 0
$$